# 3D pyramid appears scattered, with mixed up sides

Tags: c, opengl, glut

First of all I defined a structure to express the coordinated of a pyramid:

```
typedef struct
{
    GLfloat xUp;
    GLfloat yUp;
    GLfloat zUp;
    GLfloat base;
    GLfloat height;
}pyramid;
```

Pretty self-explanatory here : I store the coordinates of the uppest point, the base and the height.
The I wrote a function to draw a pyramid:

```
void drawPyramid(pyramid pyr)
{
    GLfloat p1[]= {pyr.xUp+pyr.base/2.0, pyr.yUp-pyr.height, pyr.zUp-pyr.base/2.0};
    GLfloat p2[]= {pyr.xUp+pyr.base/2.0, pyr.yUp-pyr.height, pyr.zUp+pyr.base/2.0};
    GLfloat p3[]= {pyr.xUp-pyr.base/2.0, pyr.yUp-pyr.height, pyr.zUp+pyr.base/2.0};
    GLfloat p4[]= {pyr.xUp-pyr.base/2.0, pyr.yUp-pyr.height, pyr.zUp-pyr.base/2.0};
    GLfloat up[]= {pyr.xUp, pyr.yUp, pyr.zUp};

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3fv(up);
    glVertex3fv(p1);
    glVertex3fv(p2);

    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3fv(up);
    glVertex3fv(p2);
    glVertex3fv(p3);

    glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3fv(up);
    glVertex3fv(p3);
    glVertex3fv(p4);

    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3fv(up);
    glVertex3fv(p4);
    glVertex3fv(p1);
    glEnd();



    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3fv(p1);
    glVertex3fv(p2);
    glVertex3fv(p3);
    glVertex3fv(p4);
    glEnd();

}
```

I struggled to draw all the vertices in anti-clockwise order, but probably I messed up something.
This is how I display the pyramid in my rendering function:

```
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glTranslatef(0.0, -25.0, 50.0);
    glRotatef(-angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0, 25.0, -50.0);

    pyramid pyr;
    pyr.xUp=0.0;
    pyr.yUp=10.0;
    pyr.zUp=50.0;
    pyr.base=10.0;
    pyr.height=18.0;
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    drawPyramid(pyr);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I also use an init method called before the glut main loop:

```
void init()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
    glViewport(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(35.0, 1.0, 1.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0,1.0,0.0, 0.0,1.0,30.0, 0.0,1.0,0.0);
}
```

angle is just a double that I use to rotate the pyramid, changeable by pressing 'r', but this is not relevant.It appears that the real problem is how I draw the vertices.
The problem is that the faces of the pyramid appear scattered, messed up.I would better describe this situation with an image:

[image: Pyramid]

There's a face that is too small, that is displayed and I don't know why.
If I rotate the pyramid it appears messed up, I even recored a video to describe this.
Later I could upload it if the problem is not totally clear.

PS: Many people have noticed that I am using outdated techniques.But unfortunately this is what my university offers.

**EDIT**

I forgot to say about the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinsky Pyramid");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like depth buffer isn't initialzied.

Calling `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` is not enough. You must correctly initialize glut and specify that you want depth buffer support, otherwise you won't get a depth buffer. If I remember correctly, this is done using `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|...)`. See documentation [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html#SECTION00033000000000000000) and introduction [here](http://csclab.murraystate.edu/bob.pilgrim/515/lectures_02.html). Additional info can be found using google.

--EDIT--

You're passing invalid parameter to glEnable. call `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` instead of `glEnable(GL_DEPTH)`.

Also:

1. Matrix code in display function isn't protected by glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix. Which means that every time you rotate pyramid, rotation is applied to previous transform. I.e. calling display function will rotate the pyramid.
2. glViewport is called with invalid parameters. glViewport takes 4 integer arguments, but you're trying to pass floats. Also, what's "width of -1.0" supposed to mean?
3. You have not checked any error codes (glGetError). If you tried to call glGetError after glEnable call, then you'd see that it returns GL_INVALID_ENUM.

OpenGL has documentation. Documentation is available on opengl.org. Use it and read it. Also, I'd recommend reading "OpenGL red book".

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this in the main function, that's not the problem.